# VS Code module error TimelineMax from GSAP

Tags: javascript, npm, scroll, npm-install, gsap

It might sound nooby, but I do not know what's the problem and I searched for hours for an answer on the internet. I am using React with VS Code. When I want to use MagicScroll with GSAP (TimelineMax, TweenMax) to scroll to the next anchor/section direcly on my website, in the VS Code terminal appears "Module not found: Can't resolve 'TimelineMax' in 'C:\Users\marcv\webapp\src'". I have installed with npm the following: magicscroll, gsap, greensock, scrollmagic-plugins, scrollmagic-plugins-gsap. But the error doesn't go away even though I see everywhere that gsap package contains the timelinemax package. Am I right? I'm quite new in this field.
Thanks a lot for your time and if you have any question or need more information, feel free to ask.

Specifically, I want to use this: codepen.io/andystent/pen/GRgjBdJ?editors=0010.
I see at the settings that I need those 5 external scripts. So what do I need to install to have TimelineMax package?

Comment: GreenSock doesn't recommend ScrollMagic. Instead they recommend the official scroll plugin: [ScrollTrigger](https://greensock.com/scrolltrigger/)! It's better in every way.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot! I'll look into it!